# Displaying content of unknown json file on jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

I am stuck wiht this requirement where I need to get the response from a json file and display it in a tabular format on my jsp file. The issue here is that json file can have any structure. The fields of json file I will receive in my input is not fixed. I am not sure how to code it.

Here is what I've tried so far. This is giving me `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'notes' not found on type java.util.HashMap$Node` which is quite obvious. For this type of json, I have attributes [notes, temperature, pressure and _time]. But for any other json, this can again change.

jsp code:

```
    <body>
    <h1>${text}</h1>
    <h2>This is another text</h2>
    <c:forEach items="${text}" var="pp">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${pp.notes}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${pp.temperature}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${pp.pressure}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${pp._time}" /></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
</body>
```

Servlet code:

```
    try {
            Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("C:\\Dev\\JSONExample.json"));
            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;

            Iterator itr2 = ja.iterator();
            Map<String,String> jMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

            while (itr2.hasNext()) 
            {
                Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = ((Map) itr2.next()).entrySet().iterator();
                while (itr1.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pair = itr1.next();
                    String k =  pair.getKey().toString();
                    String v =  pair.getValue().toString();
//                  System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue());
                    jMap.put(k, v);
                }
            }
            Object text = jMap;
            request.setAttribute("text", text);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I can see the contents of my map through `text` attribute which I am setting in my servlet. But not able to split it in individual attributes. `<h1>${text}</h1>` works fine.

**EDIT**: It is known that json will be of type [{a:s,j:k,l:p...}]. Meaning, there will be a JSONArray with only one element, but that element might have any number of mappings.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing jsp part to below resolved my issue:

```
<c:forEach items="${text}" var="item">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${item.getKey()}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${item.getValue()}" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```